# Error in the program citing that variable is used prior to declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

rps = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor']

diction = {'R': 'Rock', 'P': 'Paper', 'S': 'Scissor'}

human = 0

PC = 0

print('R : Rock \n P : Paper \n S : Scissor')

computer = random.choice(rps)

player = input().capitalize()

choice = diction[player]

print(computer, ' vs. ', choice)

# Check for a tie

def check_tie():

    # Checks if it's a tie
    if computer == choice:
        global human
        global PC
        print('computer = ', PC, 'you = ', human)
    return


# Check for a win
def check_win():

    check_rock_win()
    check_paper_win()
    check_scissor_win()
    return


# Check if rock wins
def check_rock_win():

    if computer == 'Rock' and choice == 'Scissor':
        global human
        global PC
        human = human + 0
        PC = PC + 1
        print('computer = ', PC, 'you = ', human)

    elif computer == 'Scissor' and choice == 'Rock':
        global human
        global PC
        human = human + 1
        PC = PC + 0
        print('computer = ', PC, 'you = ', human)
    return


# check if paper wins

def check_paper_win():

    if computer == 'Rock' and choice == 'Paper':
        global human
        global PC
        human = human + 1
        PC = PC + 0
        print('computer = ', PC, 'you = ', human)
    elif computer == 'Paper' and choice == 'Rock':
        global human
        global PC
        human = human + 0
        PC = PC + 1
        print('computer = ', PC, 'you = ', human)
    return


# check if scissor wins

def check_scissor_win():

    if computer == 'Scissor' and choice == 'Paper':
        global human
        global PC
        human = human + 0
        PC = PC + 1
        print('computer = ', PC, 'you = ', human)
    elif computer == 'Paper' and choice == 'Scissor':
        global human
        global PC
        human = human + 1
        PC = PC + 0
        print('computer = ', PC, 'you = ', human)
    return
```

Here I'm trying to make a simple Rock,Paper,scissor game, in the function check_rock_win in the elif loop, it is giving an error that variable 'human' is used prior to global declaration, although I have declared it first hand.

P.S - I'm still new to Python!

Comment: move `global human` to outside  `if` and also move other `gloal` statements

Comment: Also, please always copy and paste the error message and include it in your question, don't paraphrase it .

Comment: Okay, will remember in future. Thanks!

Comment: btw all your `return` statements are redundant and should be omitted.

Comment: Oops! I just placed return in every function while test running the program so that it doesn't throw unnecessary errors...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all your functions, place the `global` statements outside the `if` statements, otherwise, it is not always executed, for example,

```
def check_tie():
    global human
    global PC
    # Checks if it's a tie
    if computer == choice:
        print('computer = ', PC, 'you = ', human)
    return
```